# Text won't stay inside DIV

Tags: html, css

I would like the text to stay within the `DIV` even if the viewer decides to scale the text in their browser. Right now the text just goes outside the `DIV`. I'm sure I may have some code missing or screwed up.

Here is the code:

```css
.footer {
        height: 110px;
        width: 1024px;
        background-color: #000000;
        margin: auto;
        -webkit-box-shadow: 1px 2px 20px 0 #000000;
        -moz-box-shadow: 1px 2px 20px 0 #000000;
        box-shadow: 1px 2px 20px 0 #000000;
        font-family: 'Jura', serif;
        font-size: 20px;
        color: #ffffff;
    }
```

```html
<div class="footer">

        <span style="position:relative;top:15px;left:0px">
            <a href="mailto:jamie@diversedesigning.com">jamie@diversedesigning.com</a>
        </span>

        <span style="position:relative;top:15px;left:300px">
            © 2017 diversedesigning.com
        </span>

    </div>
```

Comment: You should update your question, read http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve.
You can also use jsfidle or or stack overflow bultins.
To your question: tested in chrome and firefox and looks fine.
So you should add browser and maybe also version in which you have the problem, maybe add some screen.

Comment: Are you asking how to keep the text within the footer div if the user uses their browser settings to adjust the font size? If so, you can solve that problem by removing the fixed `width` and `height` values on your footer. (One option is to change your `width` to `min-width` and your `height` to `min-height`)

Comment: box-shadow has been supported by everything for a years now, no need for prefixes. That said, where is your `overflow` rule? You gave explicit dimensions, the content doesn't fit, so you need that value set to ensure the browser does what you told it to do when things don't fit.

Answer (score 0):

Give it a try with absolute positioning with span and relative position of the parent div.

```css
.footer {
height:110px;
width:100%;
background-color:#000000; 
margin: auto;
-webkit-box-shadow: 1px 2px 20px 0 #000000;
-moz-box-shadow: 1px 2px 20px 0 #000000;
box-shadow: 1px 2px 20px 0 #000000;
font-family: 'Jura', serif;
font-size: 20px;
color:#ffffff;
position:relative;
}

.footer span:first-child
{
  position:absolute;
  top:15px;
  left:0px
}

.footer span:last-child
{
  position:absolute;
  top:15px;
  right:0px
}
```

```html
<div class="footer">

<span ><a  href="mailto:jamie@diversedesigning.com">jamie@diversedesigning.com</a></span>

<span>© 2017 diversedesigning.com</span>

</div>
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the help!

Comment: @Np :) glad to help

Answer (score 0):

**Not too sure what you're asking so i've added two possible awnsers**

**If you want it to always stay onscreen in the div**

I believe this is the one you're looking for if you want the div to stay in the same spot when resizing the screen you will need to set your div which is the parent elements position to relative
and the child element which is the span position will need to be absolute like so

**HTML**

```
<span style="position:absolute;top:15px;left:5px"><a          href="mailto:jamie@diversedesigning.com">jamie@diversedesigning.com</a></span>

<span style="position:absolute;top:50px;left:300px">© 2017     diversedesigning.com</span>

</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.footer {
  position:relative;
  height: 110px;
  width: 1024px;
  background-color: #000000;
  margin: auto;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 1px 2px 20px 0 #000000;
  -moz-box-shadow: 1px 2px 20px 0 #000000;
  box-shadow: 1px 2px 20px 0 #000000;
  font-family: 'Jura', serif;
  font-size: 20px;
  color: #ffffff;
}
```

**Text slightly outside of the div?**

I'm not too sure why its clips the edge like that but you can put some padding in your footer div to keep them away from the edges

I've just added it to your **css** below.

```
.footer {
height:110px;
width:1024px;
background-color:#000000; 
margin: auto;
-webkit-box-shadow: 1px 2px 20px 0 #000000;
-moz-box-shadow: 1px 2px 20px 0 #000000;
box-shadow: 1px 2px 20px 0 #000000;
font-family: 'Jura', serif;
font-size: 20px;
color:#ffffff;
padding:15px;
}
```

you could also just change the left value of your first span to keep it away from the edge

```
<span style="position:relative;top:15px;left:5px"><a href="mailto:jamie@diversedesigning.com">jamie@diversedesigning.com</a></span>
```

**Hopes any of this helps!**

**JSFiddle link:** https://jsfiddle.net/gaL494yf/

Comment: Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

You could simply add padding to the div with pixel values or view - width.

```css
.footer {
        height: 110px;
        width: 1024px;
        background-color: #000000;
        margin: auto;
        -webkit-box-shadow: 1px 2px 20px 0 #000000;
        -moz-box-shadow: 1px 2px 20px 0 #000000;
        box-shadow: 1px 2px 20px 0 #000000;
        font-family: 'Jura', serif;
        font-size: 20px;
        color: #ffffff;
        padding-left: 15px;
    }
```

```html
<div class="footer">

        <span style="position:relative;top:15px;left:0px">
            <a href="mailto:jamie@diversedesigning.com">jamie@diversedesigning.com</a>
        </span>

        <span style="position:relative;top:15px;left:300px">
            © 2017 diversedesigning.com
        </span>

    </div>
```